# How to call one controller from two separate button clicks

Tags: ios

I have view controller I want to load different web pages on button clicks.
I have single view controller where i can load web page.

Button click events

```
- (IBAction)btnResortTVTouch:(id)sender {

    GlobalWebViewController *globalWebViewController1 = [[GlobalWebViewController alloc] init];
    globalWebViewController1.strUrlName = @"http://www.youtube.com/user/xyz";
    [self presentViewController:globalWebViewController1 animated:YES completion:nil];
    [globalWebViewController1 selectPageLink];
}

- (IBAction)btnPIntrestTouch:(id)sender {
    GlobalWebViewController *globalWebViewController = [[GlobalWebViewController alloc] init];
    globalWebViewController.strUrlName = @"http://www.pinterest.com/xyz/";
    [self presentViewController:globalWebViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
    [globalWebViewController selectPageLink];
}
```

It gives error

```
2013-12-19 03:00:17.885 RWNewYork[5941:907] Warning: Attempt to present GlobalWebViewController: 0x80c8e90  on FiveViewController: 0x81af490 which is already presenting GlobalWebViewController: 0x80826e0
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably copied the first button, that is how you created the second one in the storyboard, and now it has 2 separate actions. So for one of your buttons both methods are called. Right-click on them in the storyboard and you can see the actions attached.

**Edit:**

Maybe you should call the `selectPageLink` method from the completion block of the presentation.

Answer (score 0):

It's telling you that you've already presented a `GlobalWebViewController` from your `FiveViewController`, and you're trying to present another `GlobalWebViewController` from it as well, which isn't possible. So your button press must be somehow calling both methods, or calling one of them twice.